# ReSharper 2016 - Disable Refactoring

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper

I like Visual Studio's refactoring process much better than ReSharper's. Is there a way to disable ReSharper's entire refactoring tools?

Answer (score 2):

Found it: Environment -> Keyboard & Menus -> Override Visual Studio refactorings